# shopify.Order.find(id=1400) returns error? Any ideas what might be wrong?

Tags: python, shopify

I have a shopify shop and an admin app written in django. The python api works well. However, I have not yet explored working with "order". Here is what I tried and an error I got...any idea why - and how to fix?

```
>>> o = shopify.Order.find(id=1402)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 351, in find
    return cls._find_every(from_=from_, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 490, in _find_every
    prefix_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 521, in _build_list
    resources.append(cls(element, prefix_options))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 133, in __init__
    return super(ShopifyResource, self).__init__(attributes, prefix_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 328, in __init__
    self._update(attributes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 904, in _update
    attr = [klass(child) for child in value]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 133, in __init__
    return super(ShopifyResource, self).__init__(attributes, prefix_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 328, in __init__
    self._update(attributes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 904, in _update
    attr = [klass(child) for child in value]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 132, in __init__
    prefix_options, attributes = self.__class__._split_options(attributes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 431, in _split_options
    for key, value in options.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - this was probably a bug in one of the older ShopifyAPI releases.

A simple

```
easy_install -U ShopifyAPI
```

fixes this for good.

Hope this helps.